# If A and B are two events and $P(A \cup B^c)= 0.3$ and $P(A \cap B) = 0.1$ then find $P(B)$

Tags: probability

Q: If A and B are two events and $P(A \cup B^c)= 0.3$ and $P(A \cap B) = 0.1$ then find $P(B)$.

Intuitively I can see that $B = S - A \cup B^c + A \cap B$ and thus $P(B) = 1 - 0.3 + 0.1 = 0.8$, but I'm not sure if this is a valid proof since these events would have to be mutually exclusive. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complement of $(A \cup B^c)$ is $(A^c \cap B)$.

Therefore, $p(A^c \cap B) = (1 - 0.3) = 0.7$.

$(A^c \cap B)$ and $(A \cap B)$ are two mutually exclusive sets whose union is $B$.

Therefore, $p(B) = 0.7 + 0.1 = 0.8.$

Answer (score 0):

Logically, $S - \left\{A \cup B^c\right\} = \left\{A^c \cap B\right\}$. You found that the probability of this event is $0.7$. Then,

$$P\left(B\right) = P\left(A\cap B\right) + P\left(A^c\cap B\right) = 0.7+0.1=0.8$$

as you have found.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A\cup B^c)&=0.3\\
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)&=0.1\\
\\
[\mathbb{P}(A\cup B^c)]^c&=\mathbb{P}(A^c \cap B)=\mathbb{P}(B)-\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)\\
\downarrow\\
\Rightarrow\ 1-0.3&=\mathbb{P}(B)-\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)\\
0.7&=\mathbb{P}(B)-0-1\\
\mathbb{P}(B)&=\boxed{0.8}\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: You should write your answer rather than posting pictures.

Comment: Understanding is important....no matter if it’s a picture or  statement